# EC2 Ubuntu server suddenly not working

Tags: ssh, backup, cron, amazon-ec2

I launched an Ubuntu EC2 instance in AWS and set a Cron job to take a backup of another server. It worked well until yesterday, but today, the Cron job didn't run, so the backup was not created.

To investigate, I tried to log into the server, but I couldn't via WinSCP or PuTTY. I restarted the instance, and I can now log in. Presumably, it will create a backup tomorrow, but I'd like to know the reason for the failure today in order to prevent further occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You said it was going well until yesterday, have you tried to manually run the script today?

This backup is being created or downloaded to your EC2 instance? 
If it is, are you keeping it or storing somewhere else like S3?

In my personal experience I've had problems when trying to send backups to S3 that were too large. Solved by breaking it up into smaller chunks.

You could also gain some insight by going to your EC2 dashboard, clicking on the instance and checking for the details panel at the bottom of the page. There you can see stats for status check failures, network data and more.

Another approach would be for your backup script to log data into a file for later debugging.

Feel free to update your answer with more info, like dashboard prints. I will be happy to help.

Comment: No, I didn't  tried manually . It creates an AMI for another instance so there is no chance to fail due to too large